# Moving django project to Github removes its dependency packages

Tags: django

So I'm working on a blog right now with Django and Python. I created a virtual environment and created my project there. I activated my virtual environment every time, so that whenever I do pip install Django or whatever it installs those packages to my virtual environment. However, When I uploaded my project with virtual env to GitHub and downloaded it on my laptop, and do "pip list" only 4 Django packages(pip, pytz, setuptools, virtualenv) are there. They are all different versions from the original too. My original virtual env has these packages below:

certifi            2018.11.29
chardet            3.0.4
Django             2.1.5
django-embed-video 1.2.0
idna               2.8
pip                18.1
pytz               2018.7
requests           2.21.0
setuptools         40.6.3
urllib3            1.24.1
wheel              0.32.3

Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup your python project with `virtualenv`, it install your third party packages on your local machine. That means whenever you copy or clone your repo from github to other machine you have to install all the packages again to run.

To know more about `virtulenv` please refer to [this awesome tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).

If you want to build your django project machine independent then I guess Docker is your best bet.

Comment: My brother was saying the same thing, but however right now I deactivated my virtual environment on my PC, and it shows different packages. When virtual env is activated it shows: certifi            2018.11.29
chardet            3.0.4
Django             2.1.5
django-embed-video 1.2.0
idna               2.8
pip                18.1
pytz               2018.7
requests           2.21.0
setuptools         40.6.3
urllib3            1.24.1
wheel              0.32.3

Comment: When deactivated it shows: certifi               2018.11.29
chardet               3.0.4
Click                 7.0
Django                2.1.2
Flask                 1.0.2
idna                  2.8
itsdangerous          1.1.0
Jinja2                2.10
MarkupSafe            1.1.0
pbr                   4.2.0
pip                   18.0

Comment: pytz                  2018.5
requests              2.21.0
setuptools            39.0.1
six                   1.11.0
stevedore             1.29.0
urllib3               1.24.1
virtualenv            16.0.0
virtualenv-clone      0.3.0
virtualenvwrapper     4.8.2
virtualenvwrapper-win 1.2.5
Werkzeug              0.14.1

Comment: When you deactivate your virtualenv it shows all the packages that you've installed in global environment, in contrary when you activate your virtualenv it only shows the packages that you've installed inside your isolated environment with virtualenv.

Comment: Okay. So whenever I go to lib/sitepackages inside my project downloaded from GitHub, it shows exact same packages as the one in my desktop.I thought that means I already have all the packages installed.

Comment: Its shows just because of 'pip list' refer lib/sitepackages directory to listing out all the installed packages. I would recommend you to read through that blog post about virtualenv that I've attached with my answer. Hope its help to understand the basics of packaging for python project.

Comment: Right. So my GitHub site-packages folder contains the same packages as the one in my desktop, however when I do pip list on the GitHub version, it only shows 4 packages(pip, pytz, setuptools, virtualenv) installed.... Just confused. Thanks for answering all my questions though. I read the tutorial on virtualenv you sent me.

Comment: So wait you are saying just because a package is in site-packages doesn't mean it's installed?

Comment: No its not installed untill you explicitly installed it in different machine no matter what your site/packages contain. When you run "pip install already_installed_package_in_different_machine" in your new machine, virtualenv will rewrite/update lib/sitepackages folder.

Comment: Wow that is so weird... But now everything makes sense now since you said that. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#the-basics        <----- is this one way to resolve this issue without using Docker as you mentioned above? By creating requirements.txt with all the required packages and doing "pip install -r requirements.txt"?

Comment: I upvoted. I really appreciate your help you da best Shubho.